# Showing widget that is outside the current widgets class

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

example:
[image: example]

Let's say I have a MainWindow widget and inside that class, I instantiate two other widgets (widget one and widget two). Each widget will have a button: next and back for widget one and widget two respectively. The first widget is visible and the second one is hidden.

I would like to call a function inside the first widget that would hide it-self and show the second widget. Then the same thing for the second widget.

I could do this if I place the function and connect the buttons inside the main window but I would like to avoid that. I don't have a very good knowledge of signals and slots to know how do it or any other strategies then putting all the logic in the main window.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw


class WidgetOne(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ########
        # initialization
        ########
        self.layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        ########
        # Buttons
        ########
        self.next_button = qtw.QPushButton('Next')
        self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.next_widget)
        ########
        # Layout
        ########
        self.layout.addWidget(self.next_button)

    def next_widget(self):
        self.hide()
        # widget_two.show() # <--- This part won't work


class WidgetTwo(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ########
        # initialization
        ########
        self.layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        ########
        # Buttons
        ########
        self.back_button = qtw.QPushButton('Back')
        self.back_button.clicked.connect(self.back_to_first_widget)
        ########
        # Layout
        ########
        self.layout.addWidget(self.back_button)
        self.hide()

    def back_to_first_widget(self):
        self.hide()
        # widget_one.show()  # This part won't work


class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ########
        # initialization
        ########
        self.layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.widget_one = WidgetOne()
        self.widget_two = WidgetTwo()

        ########
        # Layout
        ########
        self.layout.addWidget(self.widget_one)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.widget_two)
        self.setWindowTitle("Title")
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Did you already have a look at `QStackedWidget`? It is a container that always shows one widget, hiding its over children. It has the benefit of also ensuring a layout that fits all widgets.

Comment: @ypnos I think that QStackedWidget will be great for what I want to do. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must make the connection where you can access both objects (the sender and receiver).

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw


class WidgetOne(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.next_button = qtw.QPushButton("Next")
        self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.hide)

        layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.next_button)


class WidgetTwo(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.back_button = qtw.QPushButton("Back")
        self.back_button.clicked.connect(self.hide)

        layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.back_button)
        self.hide()


class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.widget_one = WidgetOne()
        self.widget_two = WidgetTwo()

        self.widget_one.next_button.clicked.connect(self.widget_two.show)
        self.widget_two.back_button.clicked.connect(self.widget_one.show)

        layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget_one)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget_two)
        self.setWindowTitle("Title")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: didn't know you could connect two methods to one event  ...`+1` from me @eyllanesc

Comment: @JakubSzlaur A signal can be connected to "n" slots, and a slot can be connected to "n" signals, that's the key to Qt

Comment: Never needed to use this but it is nice to know that honestly!

Comment: @JakubSzlaur On the other hand I see that in your code you have `self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.signal_next_widget.emit)` but it is not necessary to use emit since you can also connect a signal to another signal so you can replace it with `self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.signal_next_widget)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `QtCore.pyqtSignal` module for this:

Create the module like this (outside of the constructor):

```
class WidgetOne(qtw.QWidget):
    signal_next_widget = QtCore.pyqtSignal() #Here

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    ...
```

Then connect that signal in the `MainWindow`:

```
self.widget_one.signal_next_widget.connect(self.next_widget)
self.widget_two.signal_back_to_first_widget.connect(self.back_to_first_widget)
```

Add the methods `back_to_first_widget` and `next_widget` to the `MainWindow` and change them accordingly:

```
def back_to_first_widget(self):
    self.widget_two.hide()
    self.widget_one.show()

def next_widget(self):
    self.widget_one.hide()
    self.widget_two.show()
```

---

This is the whole code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class WidgetOne(qtw.QWidget):
    signal_next_widget = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ########
        # initialization
        ########
        self.layout = qtw.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        ########
        # Buttons
        ########
        self.next_button = qtw.QPushButton('Next')
        self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.signal_next_widget.emit)
        ########
        # Layout
        ########
        self.layout.addWidget(self.next_button)



class WidgetTwo(qtw.QWidget):
    signal_back_to_first_widget = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ########
        # initialization
        ########
        self.layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        ########
        # Buttons
        ########
        self.back_button = qtw.QPushButton('Back')
        self.back_button.clicked.connect(self.signal_back_to_first_widget.emit)
        ########
        # Layout
        ########
        self.layout.addWidget(self.back_button)
        self.hide()


class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ########
        # initialization
        ########
        self.layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.widget_one = WidgetOne()
        self.widget_two = WidgetTwo()


        self.widget_one.signal_next_widget.connect(self.next_widget)
        self.widget_two.signal_back_to_first_widget.connect(self.back_to_first_widget)

        ########
        # Layout
        ########
        self.layout.addWidget(self.widget_one)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.widget_two)
        self.setWindowTitle("Title")
        self.show()

    def back_to_first_widget(self):
        self.widget_two.hide()
        self.widget_one.show()

    def next_widget(self):
        self.widget_one.hide()
        self.widget_two.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```